# .Net Core API CORS, lock down to only one domain (Angular app)

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, cors

I have a .net core api which I want to accept calls from one domain only. There is an Angular 4 application hosted there.

I am creating a cors policy like this...

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://www.test.com").AllowAnyHeader());
        });
```

And am loading it like this...

```
  app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
```

I would have expected only calls from the Angular app on the domain to be able to hit the api, however if I create a call in [Chrome Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) I can still hit the api directly.

What am I doing wrong? I want to lock down all traffic apart from the Angular app.

Here are more details of my startup.cs...

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();


        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCors();

        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
            app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins(new[] { "http://test.com" }) 
                .AllowCredentials()); 


            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    "default",
                    "{controller=ping}/{action=get}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();

        }
```

Comment: That's sounds interesting, what is the header response from the server ? (are you using just Kestrel ? Or with IIS pipeline)

Comment: The headers in the response look like this... Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Type →text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date →Thu, 29 Jun 2017 11:45:28 GMT
Server →Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Vary →Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that your policy is considered. Kestrel should add a header (have a look on this microsoft example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#how-cors-works)

Comment: I think it as because if you don't set it the website can't access the api, postman can always though.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem ?

Comment: I added in token authentication on calls from to the api to lock it down. I all works now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The response is easier :

> CORS headers are only sent on cross domain requests [See that example](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas)

So, when you testing in local, it doestn't work. Try to host your app on a server with a domain and call with postman. It will doesn't work.

EDIT :

Okay, it's you config file which is incorrect. You need to put `AddCors` before `AddMVC`. Because, in the executing pipeline, the framework will execute in the order of your declaration in startup ..

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                politique => politique.WithOrigins("{yourdomain}").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
        });

eapp.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
```

Comment: Thats what I was hoping but I can still call it successfully for some reason.

Comment: Okay, with you config, I get the problem. See my edit

Comment: I add an example

Comment: Thanks, I can still call it. Is there anything that needs to be done on the IIS side? This is very strange. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Hmm at this time, I do not know. But don't forget to put `services.AddCors();` before `services.AddMvc();` because it's a wrong configuration (I can see that your didn't edit your example)